# Mulesoft dynamic http routing based on the input

Tags: mulesoft, httpconfiguration

I am new to mulesoft 4.4, I can to send http request to url xyz with one http_request_configuration, but I need to select application url dynamically based on the users input payload (kind of http routing with different host), I don't know how to achieve this in mulesoft. Do I need to crate multiple http_request_configuration for this?

Kind regards
J Babu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the URL at the HTTP Request operation level. For example using a variable:

```xml
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" url="#[vars.myUrl]"/>
```

Note that you should not try to use the URL to add query parameters. Use the HTTP Request query params feature for that.